# Video JS v 4.12.7 - IE7, IE8 Issue

Tags: video.js

I am using VideoJS and it works fine in Chrome, IE9. However, when I switch to IE7, even the Demo VideoJS does not work

I get the following error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty' 
>   video.js, line 153 character 142

Is it something additional that I need to do?